# Getting total number of rows returned by a query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

Which option is faster and why?

```
SELECT
    COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY 1), -- Option 1
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER    (    ORDER BY ac.[dateupdated] DESC) AS RowNum,
FROM MyTable ac      
WHERE ac.[idstatus] = @idstatus AND ac.[idtype] = @idtype

SET @TotalRecords = @@ROWCOUNT -- Option 2
```

The idea is in DEV the difference between 2 option is 1 second, but in PROD, both options are very close to 0 (0.03 sec).

Comment: I'd expect the @@ROWCOUNT to always be faster, since it's set by any assignment (including a select such as yours) anyway, even if it's not read, and it's a simple variable stored in server memory. If it's the slower option, I'd be flabbergasted. As for behaviour in production, the SQL server could simply decide that it's trivial to cache the results of this query, based on various statistics, so it could very well just return chached results all the time, not to mention it can optimize the query plan at will. But then again, what's the issue? Are you just curious or trying to solve a problem?

Answer (score 2):

In practice, I've found out that `count over` is very slow, especially with complicated queries. Not to mention that you now have a count on every row in your result set.

If you generate your queries dynamically, it's actually much faster to first do a `select count(*)` (with all your filters etc.) and then do the actual select you want.

I'm not sure if you can rely on `@@ROWCOUNT` being correct in all cases. For example, what does it return if you add paging to your query etc? I expect it will return the number of returned rows (ie. Page size) rather than the total.